# What is XNoMonomorphismRestriction?

Tags: haskell, monomorphism-restriction

[This page](http://nlpwp.org/book/chap-intro.xhtml) usages

`$ ghci -XNoMonomorphismRestriction`

to start the haskell interpreter.

What does `XNoMonomorphismRestriction` switch mean?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It turns off the [Monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction), which restricts values which are not defined using "function notation"¹ to have a non-polymorphic type.

---

¹ By "not using function notation" I mean that they're defined as `foo = something` and not `foo bar = something`, i.e. the definition does not contain explicit arguments.